# Incapsula blocks the HTML upload files containing dangerous tags

Tags: .net, vb.net, silverlight, file-upload, stream

My website is now being used Incapsula (WAF) to secure it on the internet. And the problem here is, on my website, there is a functionality that allows a user to upload HTML files. If the files contain dangerous tags such as `<script>`, `<iframe>`,... Incapsula will block that request and the result is that the HTML file is not uploaded to server folder...

Here is the snippet code for that functionality:

After selecting the HTML file, and hit Upload button, it will call:

```
'ofd is OpenFileDialog
UploadHTMLFile(ofd.File.Name, ofd.File.OpenRead())
```

And after that, there is a WCF service that will stream the file to server folder:

```
Private Sub UploadHTMLFile(ByVal fileName As String, ByVal data As Stream)
    Dim baseUrl As String = Util.BuildAbsoluteUri().AbsoluteUri
    Dim ub As New UriBuilder(baseUrl & "myreceiver.ashx")
    ub.Query = String.Format("filename={0}", fileName)
    Dim c As New WebClient()
    AddHandler c.OpenWriteCompleted, Sub(sender, e)
                                         PushData(data, e.Result)
                                         e.Result.Close()
                                         data.Close()
                                     End Sub
    c.OpenWriteAsync(ub.Uri)
End Sub

Private Sub PushData(ByVal input As Stream, ByVal output As Stream)
    Dim buffer As Byte() = New Byte(4096) {}
    Dim bytesRead As Integer
    While (InlineAssignHelper(bytesRead, input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length))) <> 0
        output.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead)
    End While

End Sub

Private Shared Function InlineAssignHelper(Of T)(ByRef target As T, ByVal value As T) As T
    target = value
    Return (value)
End Function
```

It seems like Incapsula detected the content of the upload file via the upload request, then it found dangerous tags and it blocked the request.

We cannot modify the settings of Incapsula because that is security rules configured on it.

Can you give some advice in this case? Is there a way that we can modify the code to prevent Incapsula read the content of the upload file...?

Comment: You could base-64 encode the data (i.e. the HTML file) and then decode it on the server.

Comment: Yes, I also thought about that solution which I will read the content of the upload file, then I will escape < or > to &lt; or &gt;. However, there is a security rule in Silverlight that it does not allow read the content of a file in Silverlight project. So, I though another solution which I will zip the upload file so that Incapsula cannot read the text data, the upload file is now binary data. Again, the security prevents me to read the path of the file.